# How to change the ion-fab-button line height in ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

For a simple fab button like below:

```
       <ion-fab-button>Press here</ion-fab-button>
```

How to target the line-height so that the two words "Press here" will display in two lines with controllable line height?

I'd tried css line-height method with no luck. I tried to change the
white-space to normal but the line height had no effect at all. Also,
I tried to use br

```
  Press <br> here
```

but again the line height won't work at all. Please help...

Answer (score 0):

Just for those encounter the same problem.
Put a div to wrap the text, e.g. press here. 
Then you can use line-height to control the line spacing as it became block element now.